# Disk Monitoring with OpenNMS

Tags: windows-server-2008, monitoring, network-monitoring, opennms

I'm sure this has been asked before (and actually all over the net) but I'm scratching my head a little over this. OpenNMS is installed on my 2008R2 server and is picking up my nodes fine (detecting some limited serivces etc). Ideally I woud like to kick start this and get it monitoring disk space and thresholds etc. (similar to Kaseya) but all I can find on their site and other forums are references to this NET-SNMP installer and config which there appears to be a real lack of detail explaining what I need to do with this/whether I do need it etc

Anyone with any experience with this interesting monitoring software please give us a shout!

Many thanks,

T.C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Windows, the approach is the same as for Linux. OpenNMS needs to be configured to operate on specific SNMP community names. For your Windows servers, you need to [enable and configure SNMP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726987.aspx#EAAA) by adding the role/service and defining the community name and IP addresses allowed to reach the server. Restart the SNMP service when you're done.

On the OpenNMS side, you have to tell OpenNMS what SNMP communities correspond to which IP address/ranges.

- In the OpenNMS web interface, navigate to Admin > Configure SNMP by IP.
- Enter the IP range of your devices.
- Enter an SNMP community string.
- Click *Submit*

[image]

Once done, go to the specific nodes and select the *rescan* link to discover the node's SNMP information. Disk information is presented by default.

Comment: Thanks for your response! When configuring the SNMP service, you mentioned I need to define the community name and IP addresses allowed to reach the server? What is it exactly I configure?

Comment: No worries, it actually picked up all the info! (Must of configured it right :) ). Only thing is the graphs for my Disks display no info whatsoever, just a blank graph, is that normal to begin with, will it just start to log when elements now change from the first scan?

Comment: Give it 10-20 minutes.